# Passing options into man for a self-written help file

Tags: bash, man

I have a question about the syntax of manpages.

I just wrote documentation in manpage format for my little project. 
I would like to allow users to type  `man commandname option`  as in git documentation, e.g., `man git commit`, but I don't know how to do it well.
I know a "dirty" way of doing this by defining a `man()` function in `.bashrc`:

```
man()
{
    case ${#} in
        0) /usr/bin/man ;;
        1) /usr/bin/man "${1}" ;;
        2) /usr/bin/man "${1}-${2}" ;;
        *) echo "Too many arguments" ;;
    esac
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to improve my documentation so my users can pass an option into `man`?

Comment: Why do you consider using a function "dirty"?

Answer (score 2):

The man page for man explains how giving pairs of names on the command line are handled specially:

> ```
>    --no-subpages
>           By default, man will try to interpret pairs of manual page names
>           given on the command line as equivalent to a single manual  page
>           name  containing  a  hyphen or an underscore.  This supports the
>           common pattern of programs that implement a  number  of  subcom-
>           mands,  allowing  them to provide manual pages for each that can
>           be accessed using similar syntax as would be used to invoke  the
>           subcommands themselves.  For example:
>             $ man -aw git diff
>             /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff.1.gz
> ```

So you just need to provide separate man page files for each of your options, just like git provides `git.1.gz` and `git-diff.1.gz` and so on, and you will automatically get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a feature in [mandb man](http://man-db.nongnu.org/), the implementation commonly seen on Linux distributions. From [`man 1 man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html):

```
--no-subpages
  By  default,  man  will  try  to  interpret pairs of manual page names given on the
  command line as equivalent to a single manual page name containing a hyphen  or  an
  underscore.   This  supports the common pattern of programs that implement a number
  of subcommands, allowing them to provide manual pages for each that can be accessed
  using  similar  syntax  as would be used to invoke the subcommands themselves.  For
  example:

    $ man -aw git diff
    /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff.1.gz
```

So all you need to is have a manpage properly named as `<command>-<subcommand>`.

This may not be a feature in other implementations. For example, macOS `man` doesn't support it:

```
~ man git commit
# shows git manpage
No manual entry for commit
```